# Android Studio 3rd Party Library Integration

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got to integrate a 3rd party library in to My Android Studio project and that works great without any issue.

It asks to add following configuration to the **project**'**s** build.gradle (sample configuration as follows)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         maven {
            url "http://link/location"
         }
    }
}
```

And then to add dependencies to the **app.gradle** as follows

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'xxx.xx:xxx:1.11.0:@aar'
}
```

---

But my requirement here is to create a library module (with in the project) that wraps this 3rd party library integration with in that.

Idea is to distrubute my library that contains few public methods (that use this 3rd party library methods in that) to others to integrate with in their apps.

As I mentioned earlier to use this 3rd party library I need to use their own Maven Repository and asks to place setting in Projects build.gradle. But as I want to warp all within My Library Module I just tested adding **repository** bit in to **Library Module's** build.gradle. But this provides compile errors.

```
 repositories {
    jcenter()
     maven {
        url "http://link/location"
     }
 }
```

My Question is can I achieve what I am trying to do? If so what I am missing here. Thanks

**EDITS**

Briefly what I am trying to do.

This 3rd party library is not available in standard jcenter or mavenCentral repositories. Instead it resides on their own Maven Repository Server. That's why when need to integrate it asks to specify server location in root level (project) build.gradle as follows. Then I can add dependencies...

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
         maven {
            url "http://link/location"
         }
    }
}
```

But as I want to wrap up this integration within Library Module tried to add above repository location in to gradle.build with in My Library Module.

So I can Access those classes but Main Application that compile MY Library project saying can't resolve libraries in 3rd party Library location. Actually Main Application should NOT want to know as long as My Library Module knows it...

Comment: Well, if you do not have `compile 'xxx.xx:xxx:1.11.0:@aar'`, how do you expect your library module to have access to the code from `compile 'xxx.xx:xxx:1.11.0:@aar'`? This is not unique due to the AAR being located in a different repository -- if you want to use a library, you will need to have access to that library's code, typically via a `compile` statement.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I basically can access the classes in that 3rd party library and use them. But when try to install in the phone provide reference error. Wonder if that's because I havent specify Maven LINK in root build.gradle and instead with in Library module. All I can't understand here is, theoretically is this what I am trying to do is possible or NOT.

Comment: Also I have added "xxx.xx:xxx:1.11.0:@aar" in dependencies block under build.gradle in Library module.

Comment: "theoretically is this what I am trying to do is possible or NOT" -- it is unclear what it is that you are trying to do. If your question is "can App A compile against Library B, which compiles against Library C?", then the answer is "yes".

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, Please check the EDITS section in my Question.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually Main Application should NOT want to know as long as My Library Module knows it

If the third-party module is open source, fork it, put your wrapper code in the fork, and ship the fork by your own means.

If the third-party module is not open source, discuss with the vendor what your options are for distributing this code by some other means (e.g., your own internal repository, alongside your own library).